# Checking if dataframe groups contain values from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do I print/return the value based on values from another column?

```
analyse = input[['SR. NO', 'COUNTRY_NAME']]
print(analyse)

SR. NO    COUNTRY_NAME
     2          Norway
     2         Denmark
     2         Iceland
     2         Finland
     3         Denmark
     3         Iceland
     4         Finland
     4          Norway
```

Here, I want to **check** if **Norway** ***or*** **Denmark** are **present** for ***every SR. NO***, *return those serial numbers where **either** one of these 2 countries **aren't found!*** I tried using groupby and iterating over countries but that didn't help. I'm stuck at that point.

So, the **expected output** is:

```
[3,4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set.issubset` for test if all values of list exist per groups:

```
L = ['Norway', 'Denmark']
s = set(L)
out = df.groupby('SR. NO')['COUNTRY_NAME'].apply(lambda x: s.issubset(x))
```

Thank you @yatu and @taras for improvement:

```
s = frozenset(L)
out = df.groupby('SR. NO')['COUNTRY_NAME'].apply(s.issubset)
```

Then filter index of only `True`s values:

```
out = out.index[~out].tolist()
print (out)
[3, 4]
```

Another solution with filter in list comprehension:

```
L = ['Norway', 'Denmark']
s = set(L)
out =  [k for k, v in df.groupby('SR. NO')['COUNTRY_NAME'].apply(set).items() 
               if not s.issubset(v)]
print (out)
[3, 4]
```

Comment: You can `apply(s.issubset)` directly without wrapping it in `lambda`

Comment: @taras - tested and get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`

Comment: Well, nice to know. So pandas stores it in some kind of dict then.

Comment: Yes @taras . It does work though if you define `s` as a `frozenset`. Which turns into a nice simplification

Comment: @jezrael One last question, Can I check which country is missing for respective Sr. No? If yes, how do I get that list or maybe dict?

Comment: @YashGhorpade - Can you be more specific? Do you think `df = df[df['SR. NO'].isin(out) & ~df['COUNTRY_NAME'].isin(L)]` ?

Comment: @jezrael I meant, return a dictionary of Sr. No and Country Name that doesn't have specific Countries for that Sr. No. 
Example Output: {'3': ['Normay'], '4': ['Denmark'], '5': ['Norway', 'Denmark']}
OR
Example Output: (('3', ('Normay')), ('4', ('Denmark')), ('5', ('Norway', 'Denmark')))

Comment: @YashGhorpade - I understnad now, use `difference` like `s = df.groupby('SR. NO')['COUNTRY_NAME'].apply(lambda x: list(s.difference(x)))
d = s[s.astype(bool)].to_dict()`

Comment: @YashGhorpade - `s[s.astype(bool)]` is used for remove empty lists, for `2` group.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you so much. It worked as intended! :-)

Comment: What I don't understand here is that we compare the ['Norway','Denmark'] subset to each group, while, actually we could only check the whole list of Country_Name by using groupby.unique().
Could someone care to explain please?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), `groupby` `SR.NO`, take the `sum` of each group and check which is less than `2` (meaning that `0` or `1` distinct elements in the list are contained):

```
l = ['Norway', 'Denmark']
out = (df.drop_duplicates()
         .COUNTRY_NAME.isin()
         .groupby(df['SR. NO'])
         .sum() 
         .lt(len(l)))
out.index[out].values.tolist()
# [3, 4]
```

Comment: So if there are 4 countries that I want to check, I should change the value 2 from 4? Did I get it right or I'm misinterpreting it?

Comment: Yes that is right. For simplicity, define the list separately, and take the length. I will update @YashGhorpade